keep existing values on form submit, but reset on form exit?
I have an apps script web form where I want to make sure the supervisor and substation dropdowns maintain their values when an agent is in the form submitting multiple entries. Once the exit the form, I'd like to reset all dropdowns and text boxes.
 // Function to save submitted values to local storage
  function saveSubmittedValues() {
    var supervisor = document.getElementById("supervisor").value;
    var substation = document.getElementById("substation").value;
    
    // Save submitted values to local storage
    localStorage.setItem("supervisor", supervisor);
    localStorage.setItem("substation", substation);
  }
 // Function to pre-fill dropdowns with saved values from local storage
  function prefillDropdowns() {
    // Retrieve saved values from local storage
    var supervisor = localStorage.getItem("supervisor");
    var substation = localStorage.getItem("substation");

    // Pre-fill supervisor dropdown
    if (supervisor) {
      document.getElementById("supervisor").value = supervisor;
    }

    // Pre-fill substation dropdown
    if (substation) {
      document.getElementById("substation").value = substation;
      // Trigger the onchange event of substation dropdown to populate parcels
      getParcels(substation);
    }
  }

// Call the setDefaultDate function when the page is loaded
window.onload = function() {
    setDefaultDate();
    prefillDropdowns();
};

rest of html/javascript code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <title>Daily Contact Form </title>
  <style>
    /* Your CSS styles here */
    body {
      font-size: 15px;
      background-color: #f0f8ff;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif; /* Light blue background color */
    }
    .container {
      width: 50%;
      margin: 0 auto; /* Center the container horizontally */
      text-align: center; /* Center the content inside the container */
      padding-top: 20px; /* Add space at the top */
    }
    h1 {
      margin-top: 20px; /* Add space between header image and header text */
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    select {
      width: 50%; /* Set the width of dropdown menus to fill the container */
      font-size: 12px; /* Set font size for dropdown values */
      text-align-last: center; /* Align dropdown selections in the middle */
    }
    /* Additional styling to center-align dropdown selections */
    option {
      text-align: center;
    }
    textarea {
      height: 100px;
      width: 250px;
      font-size: 12px;
      width: 100%; /* Set font size for textarea */
    }
    input[type="submit"] {
      font-size: 12px; /* Set font size for submit button */
    }
    .submit-message {
      color: red;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
    .landowner-info {
      float: center;
      margin-top: 20px;
      padding: 10px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      width: 100%; /* Extend size of landowner info box */
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
  <script>

// Function to set the default date to today's date
function setDefaultDate() {
  var today = new Date();
  var day = today.getDate();
  var month = today.getMonth() + 1; // Months are zero indexed
  var year = today.getFullYear();

  // Format the date as YYYY-MM-DD for the input field
  var formattedDate = year + '-' + (month < 10 ? '0' : '') + month + '-' + (day < 10 ? '0' : '') + day;

  // Set the default value of the date picker input field directly
  var datePicker = document.getElementById("datePicker");
  datePicker.setAttribute("value", formattedDate);

  // Set the value of the text box to the same date
  datePicker.value = formattedDate;
}


function updateMaxStatusAndLandownerInfo(parcelId) {
  updateMaxStatusForParcel(parcelId); // Call updateMaxStatusForParcel with the selected Parcel ID
  getLandownerInfo(parcelId); // Call getLandownerInfo with the selected Parcel ID
}

    function updateParcelInfo(landowner) {
      // Trigger search in "Raw Data" worksheet for landowner value
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(parcelIds) {
        var parcelIdDropdown = document.getElementById("parcelId");
        parcelIdDropdown.innerHTML = "";
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = "";
        option.text = "";
        parcelIdDropdown.appendChild(option);

        // Populate Parcel ID dropdown with matching rows from columns U3:U
        parcelIds.forEach(function(parcelId) {
          var option = document.createElement("option");
          option.value = parcelId;
          option.text = parcelId;
          parcelIdDropdown.appendChild(option);
        });
      }).getParcelIdsByLandowner(landowner); // Call server function to get matching parcel IDs
    }

function getLandownerInfo(parcel) {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(landownerInfo) {
    document.getElementById("landowner-info-content").innerText = landownerInfo;
  }).getLandownerInfo(parcel);
}

    function getParcels(substation) {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(parcels) {
        var parcelDropdown = document.getElementById("parcel");
        parcelDropdown.innerHTML = "";
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = "";
        option.text = "";
        parcelDropdown.appendChild(option);

        // Sort the parcel options alphabetically
        parcels.sort().forEach(function(parcel) {
          var option = document.createElement("option");
          option.value = parcel;
          option.text = parcel;
          parcelDropdown.appendChild(option);
        });

        // Update max status immediately after selecting parcel
        var selectedParcel = parcelDropdown.value;
        updateParcelInfo(selectedParcel);
      }).getParcels(substation);
    }

// Inside the updateMaxStatusForParcel function, where the status dropdown is being populated
function updateMaxStatusForParcel(parcel) {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(maxStatus) {
    var statusDropdown = document.getElementById("status");
    statusDropdown.innerHTML = ""; // Clear previous options

    // Define status options in the desired order
    var statusOptions = ["", "Assigned to Agent", "Outreach", "Negotiating", "Pledged", "Signed", "Dropped"];

    // Add options to the dropdown in the defined order
    statusOptions.forEach(function(status) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = status;
      option.text = status;
      if (status === maxStatus) {
        option.selected = true; // Select the option if it matches the max status
      }
      statusDropdown.appendChild(option);
    });
  }).getMaxStatusForParcel(parcel);
}

  // Function to save submitted values to local storage
  function saveSubmittedValues() {
    var supervisor = document.getElementById("supervisor").value;
    var substation = document.getElementById("substation").value;
    
    // Save submitted values to local storage
    localStorage.setItem("supervisor", supervisor);
    localStorage.setItem("substation", substation);
  }
 // Function to pre-fill dropdowns with saved values from local storage
  function prefillDropdowns() {
    // Retrieve saved values from local storage
    var supervisor = localStorage.getItem("supervisor");
    var substation = localStorage.getItem("substation");

    // Pre-fill supervisor dropdown
    if (supervisor) {
      document.getElementById("supervisor").value = supervisor;
    }

    // Pre-fill substation dropdown
    if (substation) {
      document.getElementById("substation").value = substation;
      // Trigger the onchange event of substation dropdown to populate parcels
      getParcels(substation);
    }
  }

// Call the setDefaultDate function when the page is loaded
window.onload = function() {
    setDefaultDate();
    prefillDropdowns();
};

function validateForm() {
  var isValid = true;
  var supervisor = document.getElementById("supervisor").value;
  var substation = document.getElementById("substation").value;
  var parcel = document.getElementById("parcel").value;
  var parcelId = document.getElementById("parcelId").value;
  var status = document.getElementById("status").value;
  var date = document.getElementById("datePicker").value;
  var comment = document.getElementById("comment").value;

  // Check if any field is null or blank
  if (!supervisor || !substation || !parcel || !parcelId || !status || !date || !comment) {
    document.getElementById("submit-message").innerText = "All fields must be filled.";
    return false; // Prevent form submission
  }

  // Save submitted values to local storage
  saveSubmittedValues();

  // Disable form submit button to prevent resubmission
  document.getElementById("submit-button").disabled = true;

  return true; // Allow form submission
}


    // Prevent form resubmission popup on page reload
    if (window.history.replaceState) {
      window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function () {
        window.history.replaceState(null, null, window.location.href);
      });
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/16QsZja.png" alt="Header Image" style="width: 100%; max-width: 200px;">

    <h1>Daily Contact Form</h1>

    <form method="post" action="<?= getUrl() ?>" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
      <label>Land Agent</label><br>
      <select name="supervisor" id="supervisor">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Dan">Dan</option>
        <option value="Ian">Ian</option>
        <option value="Parker">Parker</option>
      </select><br><br>

      <label>Substation</label><br>
      <select name="substation" id="substation" onchange="getParcels(this.value)">
        <option value=""></option>
        <? var subs = getDistinctSubstations(); ?>
        <? subs.sort().forEach(function(sub) { ?>
          <option value="<?= sub ?>"><?= sub ?></option>
        <? }); ?>
      </select><br><br>

      <label>Landowner</label><br>
      <select name="landowner" id="parcel" onchange="updateParcelInfo(this.value)">
        <!-- Parcel dropdown will be populated dynamically -->
      </select><br><br>

      <label>Parcel ID</label><br>
      <select name="parcelId" id="parcelId" onchange="updateMaxStatusAndLandownerInfo(this.value)">
        <!-- Parcel ID dropdown will be populated dynamically -->
      </select><br><br>

      <label>Status</label><br>
      <select name="status" id="status">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Assigned to Agent">Passed to Agent</option>
        <option value="Outreach">Outreach</option>
        <option value="Negotiating">Negotiating</option>
        <option value="Pledged">Pledged</option>
        <option value="Signed">Signed</option>
        <option value="Denied">Denied</option>
      </select><br><br>

<label for="date">Date</label><br>
<input type="date" name="date" id="datePicker"><br><br>

      <label>Comment</label><br>
      <textarea name="comment" id="comment"></textarea><br><br>

      <input type="submit" name="submitButton" id="submit-button" value="Submit" />
      <span id="submit-message" class="submit-message"></span>
    </form>
<div class="landowner-info">
  <h2>Landowner Info</h2>
  <p id="landowner-info-content"></p> <!-- Display landowner information -->
</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>

is there an easy way to do this?

Just set the  values equal to "" after passing the form obj to the submit handler using document.getElementById().

You mean like this after the localstorage.setitem lines?
document.getElementById("supervisor").value = "";
document.getElementById("substation").value = "";
 }
Because I tried this and it did not show "" when I closed out of the form and reopened it. it's still the same two dropdown values held in local storage

If you would simplify the example to focus on just the question you are asking then it would be easier to resolve because the code could be a lot simpler.  An [mcve] should focus on just your question not your entire code.
